# Q&A sites wrongfully discourage people from thinking for themselves with respect to Q&A sites

Tags: discussion, behavior, self-governance

Lately I've been seeing a lot of questions on Meta from people who apparently don't want to think for themselves about how they should behave on Stack Overflow.

Ordinarily on a site that claims to be **run by its users** (tm) one would think that one could just do whatever one feels is right until someone else tells one that it's wrong. Instead these users rush to Meta to ask what the best way to behave should be. That's crazy. Just do what you think is right. Why are you so hung up what other people think is the correct way to behave? You have the privileges granted by your arbitrary number to do great things. Just do great things. Don't second-guess yourselves.

Somehow I think this is related to the nature of Stack Overflow. Neil Butterworth commented in [this highly relevant question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58924/should-i-remove-0-vote-answers) that SO is a magnet for people with OCD. I think it's a bit more sinister than that. I think the nature of SO as a place to ask questions makes people feel they should always defer to other people with respect to their questions.

Ergo, when people wonder something they rush to ask a question about how to use the software instead of remembering that the software is designed to be self-moderating: that they should behave as they see fit and not bother the rest of us with their weird little dilemmas about every tiny little thing.

Realistically I'm not sure if it's that SO encourages asking meta questions by force of habit or if it just attracts the kinds of people who defer, defer, defer. All I know is that I find it sad that there are so many people who are so quick to do it. Whatever happened to the freedom to govern oneself? Do these people not feel confident enough in themselves to make their own decisions?

Comment: @devinb: I am Canadian and so I see a lot of these people in real life, too. It's highly disturbing. But I see them on Meta *more*. I get the feeling we're breeding them somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should respond to this.  What does everybody else think?

Comment: Why do you care?  I don't mean that as a snide aside, but as a real question.  What is your concern?  They are already acting as they want...and they apparently want to make sure they fit in well with the existing community, and want independent validation for their decisions.  I don't see what the worry is.

Comment: @beska: I find it disturbing. It might be like you say, but I'm not sure if that's the case. It seems more likely that they really want to defer.

Comment: Wait, you're Canadian? Something is wrong. They don't have lasers in Canada, do they? Where did you hear about such things? (I'm half-Canadian myself, so this comment is half okay, and half offensive.)

Comment: @Weblog: but more seriously...is deference really that big of a deal?  To defer to societal convention is to fit in...if they were deferring on issues of morality or ethics, that would be one thing, but if they're deferring to the (semi)-arbitrary, but sometimes unknown, rules of the society they are trying to integrate themselves into, well, that just seems wise.  People that work to show that they are trying to get along are (generally) treated well, and in a reputation based system, that seems like it can only help.

Comment: Only a small percentage of people will do what they think is right (in a community setting like SO) without any validation.  Most people will probably want to seek approval from others on meta and feel more confident afterwards.

Comment: @Miyagi: That seems weird. Why do people feel they need approval for doing what they think is right? Regulations exist to restrict, not enable. You should feel free to do what you think is right unless explicitly disallowed rather than feeling the need to ask for permission to do something before you do it.

Comment: @beska: You appear to be mistaking SO as a social network. Questions and answers are what are important on SO, not weird little details about how you think different features ought to be interpreted. The integration into SO should end with understanding the feature set with the idea that you should strive to do what you think is right.

Comment: @Welbog - there is a difference between social norms and regulations. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*. When people ask questions about how to behave they are getting a sense for SO's norms.

Comment: @Weblog: In theory, I think that's right.  In practice, if it were that easy, Meta wouldn't even need to exist.  The example that you're quoting in your question is a good one: someone has come up with a scenario where, after thinking about it, he *isn't sure* what the right answer is, so he's asking for input.  He can see what the general consensus is, why they think it, and go on from there, agreeing or disagreeing as he sees fit.

Comment: @Jon: If I can do something, then I'd damn well better do it as often and with as much gusto as possible so that the deferrers can't take it away from me. Having the ability to do something and having the judgement to determine when it is appropriate to do that are paramount. If I can do something, it should be up to me to decide how and when to do it. With respect to Stack Overflow features, I decide for myself how to use them and I find it disturbing that people defer to others before acting.

Comment: @beska: My point is that there is no right answer. It's up to him to decide and he shouldn't have asked about it at all. He's confused himself into thinking that he needs to ask permission to do something.

Comment: @Welbog - if you want to live in a world with minimal regulation, you have to exercise restraint and avoid abusing that which you are not prohibited from doing. Otherwise, regulations will arise to force you to obey the norms.

Comment: @Weblog: ...and, let's face it...SO *is* a social network.  The social aspect of it is downplayed compared with many sites, but the fact that we know who the various people are, and have ideas and preconceptions about them proves it.  People who stand out for one reason or another (You, Jon Skeet, Rich B, etc.) will gain a reputation, and, like it or not, that reputation affects how people view your questions and answers.  People instinctively understand this, and many want to set the tone for how they will be viewed.

Comment: @Welbog - he wasn't asking permission, he was asking for advice. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Jon: You're getting hung up on the example. Yes, he's asking for advice. It's the tone of it and the frequency of questions like that from other users that I find disturbing.

Comment: @Weblog: But does he know there's no right answer?  Sometimes you can think there's no right answer, but when you ask some other people they present viewpoints and arguments to you that can sway you, and convince you that there is a viewpoint that is better.  That doesn't strike me as caving in to pressure...it's seeking advice for a non-trivial issue.  He is always free to ignore any advice or arguments presented...but asking for the viewpoints from people who may have thoughtful input about the potentially subtle ramifications of actions strikes me as responsible.

Comment: @Weblog: As for if they're just going around asking permission, because they feel kowtowed by the awesomeness of high-rep users...well...whatever. Maybe it's not ideal, but I guess it just doesn't bother me.

Comment: There's a certain irony here. Welbog wants people to behave as they see fit. Some people think it is best to ask questions on MSO about how to behave. Welbog doesn't want them to do so, he wants them to behave as *he* sees fit by not asking the questions. If we all read this post and decided to stop asking questions about how to behave, then we would no longer be thinking for ourselves, we would be letting Welbog think for us.

Comment: @Jon: I don't want people to behave as I see fit. I want to make sure that they're behaving as they see fit, as I am seeing evidence that they are not thinking for themselves. And maybe they're OK with that. And if they are then I am, too. And that's where this thread seems to be going, and I'm OK with that. But I'll still find it disturbing. And in fact I'll find it even more disturbing that so few others find it disturbing. But I'm OK with that because I'd be a hypocrite if I weren't. So stop trying to find contradictions in my behaviour where there are none. Your straw-man need more work.

Comment: When I am sitting outside and I want to light a cigar, if there are people around me, I will ask if they mind. It's simple polite courtesy -- what if the guy 5' away is allergic? I don't see the difference here. These users are asking what the societal norms are before they get slapped down the community's junior janitors and/or mods -- nothing wrong with that, IMHO. OTOH, nothing wrong with you finding it disturbing, either

Comment: @Welbog - there is no rule on SO that requires you to ask MSO how to behave. There's nothing that even suggests it. In fact, MSO is kind of hard to find! Someone who comes here to ask a question had to *think for himself* to get here and ask that question.

Comment: I am behaving as I see fit, thank you very much.

Comment: -1 don't see what's wrong with someone double checking with a community on how to act within said community.  Wisdom is not gained solely through self experience.  If there was a pattern of someone asking the same thing over and over that's different, or even closely related things over and over.

Comment: Once I've had a proper nights sleep, I'm going to give this question the consideration it deserves and write a solid answer to it. I'm too tired right now. Stay Tuned

Comment: @devinb: I'd write something sarcastic and funny about folks leaving comments saying they're gonna comment later, but I just woke up and I'm too sleepy. Don't go anywhere or do anything - I'll be back as soon as I've had more coffee!

Comment: Is Weblog part of a vote ring or something? Over and over I see him post things I would expect to get downvoted into the ground, and they get tons of upvotes surprisingly quickly

Comment: @shog9: Waiting with bated breath. Eagerly want to know what happens next. AFK.

Comment: @Michael: If my *being insightful* is surprising to you then maybe you need to re-evaluate how you view the world.

Comment: @Michael: people that agree see no need to be vocal about it outside an upvote.

Comment: @Michael: Although I tend to disagree with We(b/l)og on this one, I upvoted the question because I think it's created a valuable discussion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### MetaStackOverflow: It's about Respect

Anyone asking for help is automatically a supplicant. They are placing themselves at a disadvantage by revealing their ignorance. There are two basic ways to admit weakness (however minor). You can be respectful or you can be denigrating. Denigrating usually takes the form: "I need you to do this for me", respect follows the form "Could you help me?".

Everyone has their preferences for which way they prefer to ask and which way they prefer to be asked. On StackOverflow, the norms certainly tend towards being completely respectful. Respect is also generally the business language for consultants and developers<sup>1</sup>. Especially on StackOverflow where there is literally *zero* incentive to help "you" particularly, people have found that respect is the best way to generate results.

Because the natural inclination that developers have learned is to be respectful when they need something from someone who owes them nothing, they will carry that tendency over to StackOverflow. This includes reading FAQs, manuals, and occasionally seeking advice about the best way to, well, seek advice.

This is **NOT** an indication of indecision, spinelessness, or second-guessing. All of those things are generally bad traits. This knowledge-seeking is an indication of *interest*, *involvement*, and *engagement*. They are *actively* trying to better incorporate themselves without rocking the boat.

As a consultant, I am often new. I arrive on a project that is out-of-shape and am told to fix it. When I see something wrong, I can dive in and fix it, or I can ask someone about it. I'll cut to the punchline. When I dive in and fix it, everything else breaks. *Anyone* else on the project could have easily told me not to do what I was attempting to do, that is, trying to interact without proper respect for history. Not only that, but in not asking those people around me, I was showing a *lack of respect* for their help.

So **no**, it is not squeamishness, spinelessness or fear that causes people to post on Meta.
and **no**, it is not self-doubt, lack of self-confidence, or blind deference.
and **no**, it is not anti-democratic, or lacking in freedom.

I have **freedom** to act as I please, I have the **confidence** to know I'll do it right, and I have **respect** for the people who came before me.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Managers and clients, well, they're mostly denigrating, but they're paying to have that pleasure.</sub>

Comment: I am OK with this. I think I can find it a bit less disturbing if I think about it this way. Thank you.

Comment: This is very close to what I was trying to say, but you've done a much cleaner job of it.  Well said.

Comment: So can I say anything I want as long as I preface it "with all due respect..."?

Comment: With all do respect, your a !@#$&*$:)

Answer (score 16):

Seeking advice from others does not mean you're not thinking for yourself.

Comment: Nor does it mean that you're thinking for yourself. It's just the way these things are phrased sometimes. It just rubs me the wrong way and makes me think that they're deferring rather than asking for independent verification. I don't have anything concrete other than this feeling.

Comment: @Weblog: Then downvote them and move on to the next ... Seems to be the right answer. Personally, I'd rather have someone ask if they're doing the right thing beforehand, than come to Meta and *whine* about their closure/deletion/downvotes/what-have-you afterward.

Comment: *Personally, I'd rather have someone ask if they're doing the right thing beforehand, than come to Meta and whine about their closure/deletion/downvotes/what-have-you afterward.* @Dr.G Last I checked, they still end up whining on meta.

Comment: @perbert: Touche.

Answer (score 8):

Something related to this came up recently in a discussion on <sup>*ahem*</sup> unpaid, in-answer advertising.

One user proposed a standard format for disclosure (a polite way to say, "I endorse this product that makes me money"). There was some disagreement, but overall it received a fair bit of support. An "advertiser" saw this and assumed that it meant he was free to advertise in his answers, provided he adhered to the format...

...When some of his answers were flagged as spam, he became confused and saddened. "Why are these vigilantes flagging me?" he asked, "Can't they see that I've agreed to the format proposed above? Why aren't they reading Meta before taking action on Stack Overflow?"

But of course, most users *don't* read documentation, even when it's official and linked to on every page. It takes a special sort of person to unwrap a shiny new toy and then put it aside, untouched, while he carefully reads *all* the documentation<sup>*</sup>.

And Meta users are nothing if not "special". *Really* special. We're the sort of people who download the documentation before ever buying the product, and then go looking for *additional* documentation, written by other users, most of whom are still busy reading the documentation themselves, their shiny new toy still sitting, untouched, in the plastic nearby...

Ain't we something?

<sup>*<sub>Including the small print in the warranty and the tiny scrawled signature under the "QC" sticker...</sub></sup>

Comment: +1: Because we're definitely "something".

Answer (score 4):

> Learn from other's mistakes, you don't have time to make them all by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Two things could explain this to a degree:

- They earn rewards by asking questions here
- They are more likely to earn rewards by participating on the parent site after consulting with their peers.

Part of this is probably that people do not want to do anything that puts their reputation at risk. I don't know if thats 'good' or 'bad', its just human nature.

A significant number of people (note, I won't say ***most*** people) favor knowing the rules on how to behave prior to behaving. That phenomenon extends ***way*** beyond Q&A web sites.

Answer (score 2):

This site has been so helpful in my efforts to learn Objective C (having saved me dozens if not hundred of hours already), that I want to make sure I know how best and most properly to use it so I don't waste other people's time.  If I'm on some blog about kittens that look like Hitler I have no worries about making an idiot of myself. Here, I know that sooner or later there are going to be questions I have that haven't been answered, so I want to be able to ask them in the correct manner.

It's similar to the reason why people worry about playing blackjack appropriately in a casino...

Comment: ... now I want a real website with kittens that look like hitler...

Comment: @farseeker this does exist http://www.catsthatlooklikehitler.com/cgi-bin/seigmiaow.pl

Comment: @Jeff - that blows my mind

Answer (score 0):

Not trusting their own decisions could not be the (only) answer. Because there are leading examples where they can seek orientation, like this weird guy, who has almost 200,000 rep points and lots and lots of 0-vote answers.

So, what else? Fear. Fear to act wrong, fear to be laughed at, fear to not be part of the whole thing. Well, at least, that would explain to me, why they do not look at what other users do. Fear can block thinking.

Whatever it is, which make them post here, missing self-confidence could only be a part of the answer. They do not trust their own abilities, they do not trust their own thinking. Sounds like fear.

Answer (score 0):

People are scared to be wrong. They're scared to make waves.

Stack Overflow allows them to build credence for their ideas. If a question is highly voted or their answer is highly voted, then they know they're probably not wrong.

I care a lot about what other people think of me, but I don't let it run my life.  I admit that I get a twinge of happiness when I see people vote up a comment I make.  It lets me know I'm not crazy.