# What to do about off-topic but still useful and already voted-upon answers?

Tags: discussion, migration, answers

Sometimes an answer is useful, but rather off-topic or in other ways not applicable to OP's specific scenario. Maybe the answer is too general, maybe the question is somewhat localized (but not *TOO* localized that it should be closed), perhaps there was a slight misunderstanding between the two, etc.

In any case, the answer was deemed useful enough by some people that it has received a few upvotes, but obviously it could use a better home. That is, the answer would be a really good answer for a different question.

Let's say there no dupe.

What should be done in this case? Should a new question be asked to which the answer can be migrated? (If so, what's the protocol?) Should the answer be deleted altogether? (I've seen this happen, and honestly I don't think it's the most ideal solution)

Comment: Can we have a moratorium on these "what should I do" questions, for at least 24 hours?

Comment: @Neil: Hey man, [I tried talking about it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58931/qa-sites-wrongfully-discourage-people-from-thinking-for-themselves-with-respect)

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see the problem:

- If the answer is useful it isn't really offtopic.
- If it isn't useful it will probably be voted upon accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing needs to be done. I fail to see why anyone should be burdened with maintaining this or making the judgement calls on such a gray area. *The system works.* Good answers are up-voted, bad answers are ignored or down-voted.