# Is there an established voting etiquette?

Tags: discussion, voting

My rule of thumb has been that if it was worth my time to read it (from a knowledge pov) then it's worth an up vote. I think this puts me on the generous side of voting. The voting guidelines suggest voting up questions and answers that are "especially useful", but I find I tend to vote for Q&A that are "somewhat useful".  Though I've never come anywhere near the 30 vote/day cap.

What other rules of thumb should or do people use?  For example

1. Is it fair to say that if you accept an answer then you should vote it up?
2. If you learned something useful from answering a question, then you should vote up the question? Even if it was badly written, or a "dumb" question.

Comment: Sheez!  Don't make me ask about down voting etiquette :)

Comment: people downvote pretty liberally on meta. Don't take it personally. I'll do you a solid and cancel that one out for you :)

Comment: @Jon B.  Thanks. This is fun isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Q&A sites wrongfully discourage people from thinking for themselves with respect to Q&A sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58931/qa-sites-wrongfully-discourage-people-from-thinking-for-themselves-with-respect)

Comment: @Shog9 -- Ouch -- Thank you, sir. May I have another?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voting is 100% at your discretion. Do whatever seems right to you.

Personally, I upvote questions if I say "Ooh! Good question" when I read it. And I upvote answers when I think they are right or particularly helpful. I also always upvote the answer I accept, but that is certainly not required.

If there were more rigid guidelines, then we wouldn't need voting at all. This is basically how you can express your opinion about posts. So do whatever you think is right.