# How active are people in voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, community

I have a habit of up voting good questions/answers.
But I have no idea how active or generous are others.
Also, should we be generous in these matters?

Comment: Does it matter? Voting is a *very* personal thing. If you like a thing, upvote it. If you find a thing particularly useless (or even dangerous), downvote it. That's all there is to it. (Sidenote: you can view the number of votes in a persons profile).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all

Comment: habit ?? 43 vote in 4month ...

Comment: @Mat: according to that page, people called "Marc" are the most active voters, closely followed by Mario ... I see a distinct correlation!

Comment: @NullPointer He he :) I mean its my recent habit. I was not much concerned about this.

Comment: Oops! What's that downvote? At least explain what is the thing that you don't agree.

Comment: There are some pretty interesting patterns there.

Comment: @NullPointer High standards, maybe.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote/130054#130054)

Comment: I'm at 10,119 votes cast (9:1 up/down) in 4.25 years...or about 6.5 a day. I feel like a slacker knowing that. Vote early, vote often.

Comment: Since the introduction of the review queue's I cast a lot of downvotes.

Comment: Voting is good, just don't get carried away like some people: http://stackexchange.com/users/139603/ward

Comment: Down-votes here do not *necessarily* reflect the same things they do on the main site. Please [read the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 4):

Vote early.

Vote often.

Be generous with upvotes and downvotes alike. Don't be scared to lose that 1 reputation.