# Re activating my account

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

For the past 1 month whenever i tried to ask question in stack overflow i got a message 'Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more'. I visited the link. Based on the suggetions in that site i made some corrections in few of my earlier questions. I would like to know whether the changes i made to my previous question is sufficient to reactivate my account and when will my account be reactivated. If the corrections i made are not sufficient then please let me know what are the further corrections i would require to make, so that i can post questions in SO.

Comment: If your changes were sufficient, you'll be able to ask questions again. If not, then not.

Comment: The system works automatically. So you'll know when you'll be able to ask questions again, if you're able to ask questions again.

Comment: It looks like you're close, have you tried also writing some helpful answers that also receive up votes?

Comment: Not necessarily related to your ban, but I've noticed you have accepted a lot of answers without upvoting them.  In fact you haven't voted at all.  It is certainly not required that you do so, but if an answer helps you, you should consider upvoting it.  And that goes for other questions and answers as well.  If a question or answer helps you, you should consider voting on it.  See [When should I vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/182513) for more details.

Comment: Hi SO team, most of the questions i came across, regarding reactivation, is about what needs to be done to reactivate the account. My question is, i have taken the necessary steps as mentioned and want to know when(any specific time) will the account get reactivated. Bart's are seems to answer my question. The system works automatically. Now im able to post my questions. Thanks

Comment: @user1531912: Posting in meta also works, if your post really has quality.

Comment: Again my account has been suspended. Previously atleast the reason for suspending was mentioned. Now without reason my account is suspended and im unable to post questions. Please let me know the reason for suspending so that i can correct it and be able to post further queries.

Comment: You have asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688566/screen-capture-in-ipad-programatically) after your ban was lifted, which was downvoted 5 times. Given that you were most likely still on the edge, you're automatically banned again by the system. There's no magic here. You've got to improve the level of your questions.