# Top users of a tag: Any new privileges that could be unlocked?

Tags: discussion, hidden-features

I know a feature called **Top users** for a particular **tag**. Precisely, for answering. What I am not aware of is, are there any privileges which could be unlocked for being among the **top users** of a particular tag?

Is such feature made available already? Or, would it be a good feature to be developed and implemented to encourage the current top users of a particular tag?

As I am not sure if such a feature already exists, so I am also adding **hidden-features** tag.

I searched for a similar question before posting, to avoid a duplicate question, however I couldn't find any.

**EDIT**

I have removed the `feature-request` tag. I think folks are thinking that I am suggesting a new feature, but I am not.

I want to know if there are any privileges which could be unlocked if the user is one of the "top users" of a particular tag.

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain for the down vote? I have asked a genuine question. Explained what I need to know. Please just don't down vote blindly, at least comment the reason you think the question to be down voted. How would I know what else you expect to be added/modified in the question?

Comment: Isn't the dupe hammer enough??

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Thanks for the comment. *dupe hammer*? Sounds fancy, but what's that?

Comment: It's hard to find a relevant master question when this question isn't clear what it's on about

Comment: @random Appreciate your comment. Am I not clear? I want to know if there are any additional features which could be unlocked for a user when the user is one of the top users of a particular tag.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: [Dupe hammer link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/245360).

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I think you forget that the active MSE members are the ones who know best how the SE network of sites works. Don't think for just one of two downvotes that they are all against you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You are absolutely right. I am just concerned whether my queation is clear or not. I appreciate all the comments and answers, it is all constructive. Thanks mate :-)

Comment: I'm the top user in [this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-svg/topusers) What amazing power do you think my 6 answers and 7 upvotes should deserve?

Comment: @Robert Longson I agree just being top user doesn't make any difference. Having a gold badge for the tag unlocks the dupe hammer which is useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no extra privileges for people being one of the top users in a tag. I am a top user in the [c# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers), and I have nothing more than anyone else having the same reputation.

I don't think it is useful to differentiate more when it comes to privileges.

Privileges are given on reputation and tag score now. That is more than enough from my point of view.

In a high-traffic tag, there are usually only gold tag badge holder top users, so they have the most they can have from their tag (namely the [dupe hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/245360)). Also, when you have enough reputation, you can [suggest and approve tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). In that way you can moderate the content of the tag too.

In a low-traffic tag, we don't want to give top users too much privileges (what if you are the top user in the `rect` tag, should you be able to insta-close for example? I don't think so.

Comment: Also worth to mention the ability to create and vote for [Tag Synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) - need certain tag score before one can do that. Was going to post new answer,  but better have it all in one answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it now. So, there aren't any additional privileges being a top user of a tag. Thnks again. I am just perplexed, why down votes on my question, is it so irrelevant? I would make sure not to ask again such a question if I am really making no sense.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks. Added.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I don't know. I didn't. Maybe people think your question isn't useful. Or they [vote on it as a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250876/245360).

Comment: No disguise @Pat, the question is tagged [tag:feature-request]. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Already edited it out. Don't read so fast.

Comment: lol, true. I might edit the question myself to make it  more clear but... you know. Oh well. :)

Comment: I have removed the "feature-request" tag. I never tried to impose a new feature request, I just added the tag as a benifit of doubt. Sorry if it has created any confusion. I have tried my level best to edit my question.