# Why not show the overall reputation for all SE sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-leagues

There is clearly a very large overlap between the communities of different StackExchange sites. I think that if people find you trustworthy on one site, then you're probably still trustworthy on others.

That's why I'd like to suggest also showing the overall reputation earned on all SE sites. I do not mean that the reputation score for each website apart should disappear.

**An example**

To clear it up I will make a little example of what I'm proposing.

You've got the following reputations:

- StackOverflow - 2500
- ServerFault   - 230
- SuperUser     - 450
- **Total**     - 3180

So, when you are at stackoverflow your reputations displays as:

2500/3180

Or at least something in that direction.

**PS**: The extra 100 reputation points for joining another StackExchange site would of course become obsolete by introducing this feature.

The 100 reputation points awarded to trusted users do nut accurately show whether a user is trusted or not in my opinion. A total reputation score would make this more clear.

Comment: Is this a discussion or a feature request?

Comment: How do you see the 100 free reputation when you are trusted on another site? I can easily get a lot of reputation out of this. 100 sites * 100 reputation.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is a feature I'd like to discuss before proposing it.

Comment: Then don't post it as a feature request. [Voting is different on Meta when it comes to feature requests.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250876/245360)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Excuse me and thanks for fixing it.

Comment: No problem. I don't want your priceless reputation go to waste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is sort of already available in the form of combined flair:

[image: profile for rene on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]


[image: profile for rene on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]


[image: profile for rene on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

However that usercard can't be reached from the normal profile nor from the network profile and the global flair does not include accounts with less than 200 reputation.

You can use The Stack Exchange Data Explorer to query all databases for a specific account. The query requires an accountid and that one can be found by visiting your network account on StackExchange.com and then take the id from the url. Yours is [3821594](https://stackexchange.com/users/3821594/peter), mine is [281857](https://stackexchange.com/users/281857/rene).

You can run the query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/289970/total-rep-across-the-network-for-one-account?accountid=281857) and this is what the query looks like:

```sql
---- accountid: Account on stackexchnage.com ! "In the url on stackexchange.com"

-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO

create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #siteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
go

declare @accountid int = ##accountid:int##  -- 93484

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                         and name not like '%.Meta%'
                         or name = 'StackExchange.Meta'
declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_users ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , userid int
                            , displayname nvarchar(40)
                            , reputation int);
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_users 
               select @url
               , u.id
               , u.displayname
               , u.reputation
               from users u  
               where u.accountid = '+ cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + ';'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select 'all ' as [site]
      , 'networkwide' as [display name]
      , sum(reputation)
from #all_users
union all
select replace(site,'.StackExchange','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '.com/'
     + 'users'
     + '/'
     + cast(userid as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + displayname
     , reputation
from #all_users
order by 3 desc

drop table #all_users
```

Given that we have these options to get an idea of SE wide network reputation I don't think it should be aggregated to one across all communities or even shown. For users that only participate in one particular community it must be confusing if someone not familiar with that community *apparently* has over 20K of reputation.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean but then visible for everyone without doing a query. I would like to propose just displaying this number in your usercard and profile.

Comment: Keep in mind the global flair does not include accounts with less than 200 reputation - if association bonus counts and user got 100 accounts, it might reach really high "loss" of reputation. :(

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we should have the double reputation flair.

Why?

Your reputation is not only showing your trustworthiness on how you handle your privileges, but also how good you know the subject discussed on that site.

What would be the meaning of `1 / 40K` when it comes to gardening? I suddenly appear to be more trustworthy, maybe even an expert on gardening, while I am actually a die-hard programmer (I have 40K+ rep on SO, 0 rep on Gardening.SE). The `40K` is meaningless.

I do like the thought of having an overall list of users with their reputation across all sites, just like in every site-specific reputation league. I would subtract the 100 free reputation awarded on every site you subscribe when you are trusted on other sites though.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand me correctly. I would like your 40k on SO to stay 40k on SO. What I'm proposing is that your 40k on SO and 7k on Meta are combined to give a total score as well.

Comment: @Peter: What does this mean than? "The extra 100 reputation points for joining another StackExchange site would of course become obsolete by introducing this feature."