# Unnecessary Downvote

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have a stackexchange account where I posted a couple of questions and people were going out unnecessarily down voting posts on my
question. This is preposterous. And this restricts my ability to post
 questions.  Just because the users can't solve the questions should
 they down vote it?

Comment: And how exactly is this related to the android app?????

Comment: Isn't it the forum for technical issues

Comment: Not about downvotes you get, and I still can't see how android app is related.

Comment: Sorry... I thought this was the redressal forum

Comment: How do you know the downvoting was unnecessary?

Comment: These sites in the Network  are not [forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum). Which means you can't use it as such and if you do, the down votes are there to quickly make users aware of that. Your question proves the quality system works.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote

Comment: The OP is using the site to get answers for his homework questions - we are not a homework completion service.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I also think it's kind of funny that it was originally tagged "feature-request". I'm wondering whether the "feature" would be that people should stop downvoting OP, or whether it should be for the downvote feature to be disabled altogether.

Comment: @Fiksdal more like random tags by someone who got no clue how this site works. (Or got a clue and simply don't care)

Answer (score 12):

If you ask a question that does not show research effort, is unclear, or not useful you'll likely get downvotes.

- Your questions on Chemistry [are closed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58234/why-do-real-gases-deviate-from-ideal-gas-behavior) because you're required on that site to show in the question some understanding of the underlying concepts i.e. prior research.
- Your questions on Mathematics are [pretty much the same with a slightly different close reason](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913962/find-the-sum-of-digits-in-decimal-form-of-the-given-number).

If you keep asking questions that sites do not want you'll be restricted in asking more because answerers don't want to keep wasting their time reading and then closing them.

You'd be better off trying to improve your questions than railing against the rules on the sites. For instance you could have included what you think the answer is and why you're not sure that you have the right answer and that would have improved pretty much all of your questions.

You might also find reading the help centres on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) useful.

Comment: I think you have only seen only one of my question

Comment: I've seen them all, they are pretty much all the same, I just picked one from each site as an example.

Comment: No you haven't..... I am pretty sure

Comment: @SAditya that is not how StackExchange works, just because a question makes sense does not mean it is fit for the site. Please read through the help on each site you are posting on to find out how to ask a good question and to see what is on or off-topic.

Answer (score 10):

Judging from your questions and [one of your comments](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58234/why-do-real-gases-deviate-from-ideal-gas-behavior#comment97305_58234), it looks like you may have taken your textbook and copied some questions you didn't write yourself. *Many* sites don't appreciate this.

Questions are supposed to feature your own effort and research. Copying questions from elsewhere does not fulfill this criterion.

Please note that downvotes are not personal. They are supposed to purely reflect the content of your posts. Take them as an indicator of that, nothing more. You can then reconsider how to post your future questions accordingly. I realize that you're now blocked from asking any more questions, but it won't last forever. Provide some quality answers, and you may soon be able to ask again.

Comment: Sir I posted questions that I couldn't solve in the Indian National Maths Olympiad

Comment: Although I regret not being able to answer some of these questions

Comment: @SAditya Alright. However, questions are supposed to feature your own effort and research. Copying questions from elsewhere does not fulfill this criterion.

Comment: I post questions after I attempt them

Comment: @SAditya Then include all that in your question.